# Regular expression to return only one match

Tags: c++, regex

My CPP application is similar to a regular expression testing application in which I can enter the regular expression and the input string to see the output. I am using the cpp API `std::regex_search(inputString, match, regex)` to execute and get the match for all regular expressions. The problem I am facing here is that the `match` can have more than 1 item but I should return only one of them.

I have 2 types of input strings. For example:

1. *Name:Jake* (string with prefix 'Name:'). I am using the regular expression `^Name:(.*?)$`. Here `match` contains **Name:Jake** and **Jake**. I have to ignore match[0] and return match[1] in this case.
2. *1234-r* (string with suffix '-r') Here I am using regularexpression `^.*(?=(\\-r))`. In this case `match` contains **1234** and **-r**. In this case, I have to ignore match[1] and return match[0].

Is there a way I can modify these regular expressions so that the match will have only one item in that? **Jake** in the first case and **1234** in the second case.

This is the first time I am dealing with regular expressions.

Comment: There is no lookbehind support in `std::regex`, so no way to get `Jake` only with `^Name:(.*?)$` (equal to `^Name:(.*)`)

Comment: why that backslash before the dash?

Comment: @WalterTross, I am getting the same result with and without the backslash. I think it is not required.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is there any alternative? Like getting the required item always at the first or last index of the match?

Comment: I've never used regexes in C++, but I guess you will have to use something like `^(?:Name:\s*(.*)|(.*)-r)$` and then check which, if any, of match[1] and match[2] is set.

Comment: Your second regex should be `^(.*)-r` to produce what you want.

Comment: It is not possible to help you because your requirements contradict themselves. It is possible to just use the whole match value, or just captured value, but it is not clear why you want one in one case and the other in the other.

Comment: I am trying to change from std::regex_search to boost::regex_search (#include <boost/regex.hpp>). But there are linker errors. --- error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: class boost::basic_regex<wchar_t,struct boost::regex_traits<wchar_t,class boost::w32_regex_traits<wchar_t> > > & __cdecl boost::basic_regex<wchar_t,struct boost::regex_traits<wchar_t,class boost::w32_regex_traits<wchar_t> > >::do_assign(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?do_assign@?$basic_regex@_WU?$regex_traits@_WV?$w32_regex_traits@_W@boost@@@boost@@@boost@@AEAAAEAV12@PEB_W0I@Z) ................

Answer (score 0):

```
    smatch sm;
    string str = "Name:Jake";
  
    std::regex_match(str, sm, std::regex("^Name:(.*?)$"));
    std::cout << sm.size() << endl; //number of matches

    std::cout << sm[1] << std::endl; //you only need the second match here

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sm.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "[" << sm[i] << "] ";
    }
```